# An invitation to brownian traps to capture or destroy viruses and bacteria

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, biophysics, brownian-motion, applied-physics

I'm interested for general feedback about modern brownian traps for viruses and bacteria. In my rememberings a related reference is a column added to the article in Spanish [1] (I don't remember well what was the specific purpose of this brownian trap but it should be closely related), at that date I don't have access to this number of the journal (the journal is the Spanish edition of Scientific American).

I tried to search for the key words **brownian trap** but I can not to find the results that I want (in Spanish I believe that it is **trinquete browniano o trampa browniana** but I'm not sure). An article from a web site of the European Commission CORDIS seems that mentions in words of Armin Knoll ([2]), which I mean is a device (you can to think in a box on the table of your laboratory as proof of concept) filtering bodies according to their size, if I am right.

> **Question.** Please provide a document (answering my post as a resource recommendation providing an article(s) or book) or a explanation in your own words and knowledges about modern devices to detect (capture or destroy) bodies of sizes similar than the sizes of viruses and bacteria exploiting the brownian motion of these bodies in a device (as proof of concept $\approx$ $\text{ a box with a fluid and a specific design }$). **Many thanks.**

I know that the sizes of viruses and bacteria are very varied.

### References:

[1] W. Wayt Gibbs, *Aplicaciones de la física moderna para el siglo XXI*, Investigación y Ciencia, Nº 338 Noviembre 2004.

[2] *Brownian Motor Based Virus Detection* (https://cordis.europa.eu/article/id/428565-brownian-ratchet-can-find-viruses-hiding-in-water).

Comment: I hope that my post is suitable and interesting for your site, please add your feedback in comments, that I can to provide a response in few hours. I hope that my mention of the material from the references of journal and web site is is respectful with these sources (I couldn't find an article from an online encyclopedia with the purpose to mention these brownian traps).

Comment: Many thanks for the professor who upvoted our post.